Excel sort row with custom formula
Using Excel 2016, I want to sort my table by a row which fields MAY contain one or multiple letters at the end.



ID




3632


22895


129A


849721


84974B


290BC



I want to be able to sort this by number while ignoring the letter at the end, so the result must be:



ID




129A


290BC


3632


22895


64974B


849721



The built-in sort puts the fields with letters at the end.
Is there a way to sort this without using VB ?
Thank you all for your help !

Do you have a CONCAT function in your Excel?

My bad, it looks like I don't have CONCAT available after all. I use excel in french and I made a mistake with the function name translation. I only have CONCATENATE

Create a custom function using VBA:
Function RemoveText(str As String) As String
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
    RemoveText = .Replace(str, "")
  End With
End Function

Source

Open VBA through ALT+F11 (you might have to add the 'developers' tab);
Add a module to the workbook;
insert above code;

Use the above formula =RemoveText(A2)*1 in the first cell of your helper column; drag down for all cells. (lets say this is cells B2:B7)
In the column where you want to have the sorted data, do =SORTBY(A2:A7,B2:B7).

I don't think BYROW is available in Excel 2016, but you could do it without helper column: =SORTBY(A2:A7,BYROW(A2:A7,LAMBDA(a,RemoveText(a)*1)))


Looks like it does not work the way I need it.
Here the 290BC is after the 22895. What I need, is basically to ignore the letters and sort by numerical value.
So 290 < 22895, it should be before in the list.

@Laurent do you have SORTBY available? Also, is VBA and a helper column an option?

Yes I have SORTBY available, helper column should be fine. VBA, if there is no other option yes.

@Laurent I have edited the answer, let me know if it works for you.

@Laurent If you have sortby, then why tag Excel 2016?

With Concat, you can create a helper column with numbers only, then sort the data by that column, and finally delete or hide that column.
Formula for B2:
=--CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1),""))

And a copy down.
If CONCAT is not available you can use the following formula instead:
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(A2,1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))),""))

This is an array formula and in Excel 2016 it requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter to work properly.


Same solution but this formula is easier for my mind to follow. It may or may not be true for other future readers.  =--CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),""))

@EngineerToast I think that SEQUENCE is not available in excel 2016

As said in the comment under my question, I made a mistake, I don't have CONCAT available only CONCATENATE.
It's a shame, this looks like a clean non-VBA solution. I hope it will help others !
Thanks

I have updated my answer with another formula.

There may be shorter or more efficient methods, but this should work if you have 365 with your data in column A.
Enter the formula in a single cell and the results will spill down.
=LET(
    d, A2:A7,
    AZ, CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 65, 1)),
    n, BYROW(
        d,
        LAMBDA(arr, --LEFT(arr, MIN(SEARCH(AZ, arr & CONCAT(AZ)) - 1)))
    ),
    a, BYROW(
        d,
        LAMBDA(arr, MID(arr, MIN(SEARCH(AZ, arr & CONCAT(AZ))), 255))
    ),
    sp, HSTACK(n, a),
    s, SORT(sp, {1, 2}),
    j, BYROW(s, LAMBDA(arr, TEXTJOIN(, , arr))),
    VSTACK({"ID"}, j)
)


The formula creates a two column array (numbers and characters) and then sorts that array.

In Office 365 it's simple as =SORT(""&A2:A7)
In Older Excel if you want to do it without helpers:
=INDEX(INDEX(""&$A$2:$A$7,MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-1,MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(""&$A$2:$A$7)<=""&$A$2:$A$7),ROW($A$2:$A$7)^0),0)),ROW(A1))

Where we use MMULT to get the rank of the values converted to text and we match the number of rows (starting at 1) to the rank, to return the indexed row number of the values converted to text. Since that returns an array of all results, we need to index that as well to return the nth row.
This requires being entered with ctrl+shift+enter
Edit
I see you wanted to sort the range by the number value found in each string only and I saw you had access to SORTBY, meaning you have at least Excel 2021. You could use something like:
=LET(m,--MID(A2:A7,1,SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(A2:A7)))),
     r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(m)),
SORTBY(A2:A7,INDEX(m,r,MMULT(IFERROR(SIGN(m),0),r^0))))

Or if you have access to TEXTSPLIT:
=SORTBY(A2:A7,--TEXTSPLIT(UPPER(A2:A7),CHAR(SEQUENCE(,26,65))))
